# How to correct attribute error while working with two methods in a python class?

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I have a class defined as below;

```
class A:
    def __init__(self) ->None:
        pass
    
    def method_A(self,d,m):
        self.DATOS = d
        self._METH = m
        
    def method_B(self):
        return self.DATOS
```

I have instantiated A class as follow and trying to call a method_B from it

```
x = A()
x.method_B()
```

here it throws an error as:

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'self.DATOS'
```

How to pass an attribute from method A to method B ? without defining them in **init**?

Comment: Call `method_A(d, m)` on the object.

Comment: Yes, but in my case it would disturb some of my logics.

Comment: Then change your logic. Your requirement doesn't make sense. What do you expect `self.DATOS` to be if you never give it any value?

Comment: Without instntiating method_A() how are you going to get the DATOS value and retrun it method_B(). I think the approach you are trying to use is wrong

Comment: I have got it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare one as a class property

```
class A:

    DATOS = None

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def method_A(self, d, m):
        self.DATOS = d
        self._METH = m
        
    def method_B(self):
        return self.DATOS
```

Or declare on object initialization which is more optimal especially when the `method_B` is not a `classmethod`

```
class A:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        DATOS = None
    
    def method_A(self, d, m):
        self.DATOS = d
        self._METH = m
        
    def method_B(self):
        return self.DATOS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that without defining attribute in `__init__` you might try [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self) ->None:
        pass
    
    def method_A(self,d,m):
        self.DATOS = d
        self._METH = m
        
    def method_B(self):
        return getattr(self, 'DATOS', None) # check if DATOS is defined and return it value otherwise return None
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for the attribute `DATOS` to exist you must call the `method_A` first. Your `A` instance doesn't know about `DATOS` until you call `method_A`. In that method you declare the variable and give it a value, after that you will be able to access it.